How to rerender the Dropdown field?
I made a searchable dropdown which is a triangular thing that connects the Block to the field
Is there a way to rerender this?
Because when I search, it takes a bad shape.
If you need the code, tell me.
Before search
Before search
After search
After search

Please see [ask]. You've been told. :)
